# Returning strings from C++ dll to vb

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I have the following dll cpp file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <OleAuto.h>
using namespace std;
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BSTR func(BSTR a) 
{
BSTR buffer;
buffer = SysAllocString(a);
 return buffer;
}
```

At the vb end

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim string1 As String
    string1 = func(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox2.Text = string1
End Sub
```

The above code compiles properly but the form closes before displaying the string in the textbox. But if I return the text as an integer, it works fine...

Comment: So... debug it? The visual studio debugger allows you to debug this very thing. Make sure the DLL module is referenced by the VB project and just debug it.

Answer (score 1):

BSTR != VB.NET String i think ,,, use LPCSTR

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LPCSTR func(LPCSTR a)
```